# duplicated colors in legend of tmap object in R

Tags: r, tmap

has anyone encountered such problems with `tmap` in `R`? See the plot below. No matter which style I tried (`pretty`, `kmeans`, `jenks` to name a few), there were always duplicated colors in the legend. I also tried setting `midpoint = NA`, but the problem persisted.

Here is the code I used to create such a plot. Below the code is the vector for plotting. Sorry that `dput` seems not working with `sf` objects. Please feel free to use any spatial data to replicate the example. Feedback is always appriciated!

```
tm_shape(sfpr) + tm_borders(col = "gray") + 
  tm_polygons(col = 'Pperc', 
              style = "kmeans",
#              midpoint = NA,
              palette = viridis(4, begin = 0.48, end = 1)) + 
  tm_layout(inner.margins = c(0.1, 0.15, 0.1, 0.1), 
            legend.title.size = 1.5, 
            legend.text.size = 1.1, 
            legend.position = c("left", "bottom"), 
            legend.format = list(digits = 0), 
            main.title = "Maps on the reduction of phosphate losses (in 1000 lbs)", 
            main.title.position = "center")
> sfpr$Pperc
 [1]   -1.49   -0.02    0.12    0.27   -0.36 -247.86  -21.74   -8.88   28.63  -14.48   -0.56
```

[image]

Comment: You have 4 colors but 5 legend classes. Can you try with at least 5 colors: `viridis(6, ...)`?

Comment: @Eyayam, When I changed to `viridis(5, ...)`, it worked, i.e., no duplicated colors presented. But `viridis(6, ...)` did not work. Also if I simply use `palette = 'viridis'`, duplicated colors show up again.

Comment: Did you try it with `style='cont'`?

Comment: @Eyayaw There is no such style. Were you referring to `cat`?

Comment: `style.args="cont"` for continuous scales.

Comment: @Eyayaw Just tried that but it did not work. What a mystery :)

Comment: That is unfortunate. I think it could be because of borders + polygons. borders + fill = polygons. Use `tm_fill` instead of `tm_polygons`. Or remove the `tm_borders` line.

Comment: @Eyayaw Unfortunately, that did not work. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by negative and positive values in your dataset. If you set `auto.palette.mapping = T` (deprecated) or play around with different numeric values for `midpoint` this will solve your problem. I generated some dummy data based on your min/max values. Btw, you should either use `tm_borders() + tm_fill()` or only `tm_polygons()` since the latter one fills the polygons as well as draws the outline.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tmap)
library(sf)
library(urbnmapr)
library(viridis)

# create dummy data
sfpr <- get_urbn_map("states", sf = T) %>%  
  as.tibble() %>% 
  mutate(Pperc = runif(51, -248 ,29)) %>% 
  st_as_sf() 

tm_shape(sfpr) +
  tm_borders(col = "gray") + 
  tm_fill("Pperc",
          style = "kmeans",
          palette = viridis(4, begin = 0.48, end = 1), 
          auto.palette.mapping = T) +
  tm_layout(inner.margins = c(0.1, 0.15, 0.1, 0.1), 
            legend.title.size = 1.5, 
            legend.text.size = 1.1, 
            legend.position = c("left", "bottom"), 
            legend.format = list(digits = 0), 
            main.title = "Maps on the reduction of phosphate losses (in 1000 lbs)", 
            main.title.position = "center")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input! According to the documentation, if `midpoint` is specified, the color palette will be treated as diverging. However, what is desired here is a sequential one. That is why I set `midpoint = NA` to keep a sequential palette. Does this make sense to you?